# Excel Round() function producing #VALUE! error when given valid numeric input

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any idea why I'm getting a #VALUE! error?

[image]

When I click on Evaluate, the next thing I see is (I'm expecting 0.00):

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the data you show.  What are your windows regional settings for decimal; list separator; thousands separator?

Comment: if this is the formula `=ROUND(-7.78891262598336-9,2)` then I'm getting `-16.79` instead of `0.00` what you are expecting ,, but not the #value error !!

Comment: @Rajesh - You have missed the E from the first argument of the function, which is in scientific (or exponential) notation.

Comment: Like the first commenter, I cannot reproduce this error with the data shown. The formula evaluates correctly.

Comment: Hi @mbmast ,,, yes but u know also that XL converts the number into scientific notation when value exceeds than default,, but in my case it does't ,,, and even if put `-7.78891262598336` in cell, and apply Scientific notation will be `7.79E+00` ,and insert `09` in another,, and write  `=ROUND(a1-b1,2)` , will return `-16.79`  BUT never the ZERO !!

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Excel, the error went away.  Prior to restarting, the error was extremely consistent.  Does not leave me with a warm fuzzy feeling about Excel.